# Передвижение объекта при изменении значения слайдера

Tags: unity3d

Мне нужно, чтобы объект (куб) двигался влево-вправо при изменении (уменьшении-увеличении) значения слайдера снизу.
Не знаю как реализовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При изменении слайдера получать значение от 0 до 1. С помощью Lerp передвигать кубик от крайней левой к крайней правой позиции

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 1):

В компоненте [`Slider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/UI.Slider.html) установите значение [`MaxValue'](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-maxValue.html) на` 1`.

На кубик повесьте подобный скрипт:

```
public Vector3 leftPos, rightPos; // Указать из инспектора (или где-либо еще)
public void OnSliderMoved (float value) {
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(leftPos, rightPos, value);
}
```

Слайдеру добавьте событие в `OnValueChanged`. Укажите кубик, выберите скрипт кубика, укажите функцию. Важно выбрать функцию не статическую, а динмическую (в списке функций все динамические будут выше).

Мы используем [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) и телепортируем кубик в указанную позицию. Если необходимо можно просто сохранять целевую позицию в переменную и перемещать туда кубик любым удобным способом: с помощью физики, [transform.Translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html), анимацией — как угодно.

Comment: Спасибо большое! разобрался.

Comment: @СамирМамедов Вы можете проголосовать за ответ, нажав стрелочку вверх, и, что важнее, принять ответ, нажав на галочку.